# Multiple select into database field

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I´ve got a problem i can´t figure out: I´ve got this multiple select which i want to put into one database field (seperated by ",")...but i´m stuck at the beginning:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
    UPDATE MyTable SET `sites` = '$_POST[sites]' WHERE `id` = '$_GET[id]'");
}?>
<select name="sites" multiple="" size="13">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
<option value="4">Fourth</option>
<option value="5">Fifth</option>
</select>
```

Problem is: In my database field theres only ONE number: The heighest one I selected. For example: I choose "Home" and "Third", i´ll get a "3" ind my database field...how to solve this? Any tipps on this?

Comment: You aren't inserting it as an array so it would never work. It always picks the last number you selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will need to change the name of your `select`

```
<select name="sites[]" ....>
```

This will populate a variable `$_POST['sites']` as an array.

Then what you can do is

```
 UPDATE MyTable SET `sites` = '" . implode(",",$_POST[sites]) . "' WHERE `id` = '$_GET[id]'"
```

Comment: Thanks, i´ll try it like this! +1...and it worked. Thanks, i´ll keep that in mind!!! Really easy and helped, thanks! Accepting this in 5 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this

```
<select name="sites" multiple="" size="13">
```

to this

```
<select name="sites[]" multiple="" size="13">
```

so `sites` will become subarray of $_POST:

```
array (size=1)
  'sites' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
```

Then you can loop through it, and use the values in `IN` operator in your SQL, or split them depends on your needs

Comment: Thank you very much, +1. @DevZer0 ´s tip helped me.